# ZigZag decode/encode in Java

Tags: java, long-integer, zigzag-encoding

I'm looking for some library which can provide with the functions that can help deconding zig-zag encoded byte array into 2's complement `long`/`int` and back.

Since ZigZag is used in [***protobuf***](https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/encoding?csw=1#types) I expected that guava has something for it, but googling did not give any result. By ZigZag encoding I mean this:

```
Signed Original Encoded As
0               0
-1              1
1               2
-2              3
2147483647      4294967294
-2147483648     4294967295
```

Do I have to "reinvent the wheel"?

Comment: It is not a big wheel, 2 lines of code.

Comment: @NiVeR Not quite 2 lines. Looking at its implementation I found it pretty much scary.

Comment: https://gist.github.com/mfuerstenau/ba870a29e16536fdbaba and scroll down. OK, it's python, but nothing there doesn't have a 1:1 Java equivalent.

Comment: The page you linked has your answer: `(n << 1) ^ (n >> 63)` for 64-bit

Comment: @Arijoon which is not suitable for 9 or 10 bytes longs.

Comment: 9 or 10 bytes aren't long or ints. these are 4B(32bits) and 8B (64bit) values. https://cs.fit.edu/~ryan/java/language/java-data.html

Comment: You can also look at how protobuf does it: https://github.com/google/protobuf/blob/master/java/core/src/main/java/com/google/protobuf/CodedInputStream.java check `long readRawVarint64()`

Comment: @Arijoon I meant ZigZag encoding is a bit eccessive in the sense that the 8-bytes long may be incoded into 9 or 10 bytes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you go:

```
    Long aD = 2147483647L;
    //encode
    Long aE = (aD >> 31) ^ (aD << 1);
    //decode
    Long bD = (aE >> 1) ^ -(aE & 1);

    System.out.println(aD + "," + aE + "," + bD);
```

Comment: The problem is it does not work for longs which are encoded to 9 or 10 bytes.

Comment: You can go on and adapt the `BigInteger` type if you want to treat arbitrary lenght numbers.

Comment: @SomeName I went with just the simple logic of 
if(value%2==0){
   return value/2;
}else {
   return (long) -Math.floor(value/2d);
}